# Label the JQplot pie chart

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I am using JQplot Pie Chart.  I need the labels to appear outside the chart. How can I make that possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean data labels then you need to set the `dataLabelPositionFactor` to appropriate value greater than `1.0` and you are done.

[Example sample available here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/NYewy/57/)

Answer (score 0):

To do that yuo need to specify the placement propertie :

```
legend: { 
              show:true; placement: "outsideGrid"
            }
```

Example :

```
    $.jqplot('YOUR_DIV_ID', [['LABEL_1',2],['LABEL_2',232],['LABEL_3',22], { 
          seriesDefaults: {
            // Make this a pie chart.
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
            rendererOptions: {
              // Put data labels on the pie slices.
              // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
              showDataLabels: true
            }
          }, 
//Make legend visibile, outside the chart
          legend: { 
              show:true, placement: "outsideGrid"
              }
        }
      );
```